# Possibility of being refused entry in Schengen countries?

Tags: schengen, uk, denial-of-entry, removal

Following this [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60131/how-can-i-know-if-i-am-still-refused-entry-to-the-uk), I had a refused entry in the UK before (about two years ago) and granted a temporary admission.

I am just curious, does it mean that I will get the refused entry in other countries in Schengen area, after the UK's?

Comment: The question you referenced points out that the result cannot be predicted. Some people have success, others do not.  You can apply to the appropriate Schengen consulate for a visa if you want to nail it down.

Comment: If you get a visa and answer the border officer's questions satisfactorily during entry, have all the necessary documents e.g. return flight tickets, travel plans etc, you will sail through. Botch any of this and entry might be refused.

Comment: @GayotFow depending on nationality.

Answer (score 4):

A previous entry refusal to the UK does not carry any automatic ban from the Schengen area (to which the UK does not belong, incidentally). Even being refused entry by a Schengen country doesn't! So you won't be refused entry merely because of what happened in the UK.

But border guards have to evaluate whether you fulfil the requirements (which differ depending on your citizenship) each time you present yourself to the border and can decide to refuse entry if they deem that you are likely to disregard the conditions of your visit (e.g. by working or immigrating illegally). Your travel history and any earlier problem, even in a completely unrelated country, are part of this risk assessment and might prompt them to inquire a bit more closely.