# Entry Refusal - what does this stamp mean?

Tags: uk, denial-of-entry

Following this [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60131/how-can-i-know-if-i-am-still-refused-entry-to-the-uk), I had a refused entry in the UK before (about two years ago) and granted a temporary admission.

I am just curious, what does this stamp below mean? (there two stamps, what I am asking is the top stamp). What is this 45 XXX on the stamp for? I can hardly see any readable word on the stamp!

[image]

When I left EU via Amsterdam, the officer asked me what that is and I could not answer him. So I just told him that it was the date I left the UK.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Sorry I think the code/ number should not be shown in this public space.

Comment: For anybody else needing more details, see the other question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60131/how-can-i-know-if-i-am-still-refused-entry-to-the-uk Basically the OP was told they were "refused entry", but let in for six weeks anyway.

Comment: Why have you not accepted one of the answers provided? You have two really good answers dripping with valuable information.

Comment: @qcuk, no. You need to click the check box shown underneath the answer's score. It will turn green when you accept.  For a question like this it's important to check one so that people will stop adding more answers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You were given a code 3 leave to enter instead of a 5N. It means the IO did not have sufficient grounds to refuse you entry but had some reservations and hence 'landed' you on code 3. This means that the next IO will be aware of this since you were not given the usual code 5N stamp. The NWA 45 followed by three digits is derived from your landing card. This is your arrival number. The IO would have made notes on the back of the landing card for future reference setting out his suspicions.

BTW you were NOT given temporary admission (in the IS96 sense) as this term is used erroneously in the previous post. You were given 'Leave to Enter' since you were landed.

Comment: +1 for an impressive tour de force. A well-informed answer and it's clear you have spent some time studying the Operations Manual. You're a great addition to the site, please hang around and visit often!

Answer (score 3):

As Gayot Fow explained in [his very detailed answer to your other question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/60135/1893), you were *not* refused entry: this stamp is a standard "**[leave to enter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leave_to_enter)**" stamp, which means you *were* granted entry to the UK.  These are commonly given to everybody who is allowed to enter, but doesn't otherwise have right to abode in the UK.

[image]

The code up top is likely there to identify some combination of where you got this and who gave it.

Comment: +1 for getting the bigger picture *AND* surprising me by including a link to the Wiki's entry for LTE (didn't know they had an article about that). Also, thanks for including a standard LTE stamp!