# Documents to be carried when entering UK (or any other country) on a Visa

Tags: visas, uk

I note in many answers provided about 2nd visits or changed purpose, the respondents advise that you are likely to be interviewed by (British) immigration officer and should carry ALL the documents that you used to apply for your visa.

I do understand what that means but I do not understand WHY should I be carrying 6 months of payslips, bank statements, proof of property ownership etc.

Surely the output being an issued visa assessed all of that. If I can demonstrate on entry that I have means to support myself (currency in hand), means to exit (booked return ticket) and still have a reason to visit (in my case - sister turning 60 still resident in UK) then that should suffice.

I know the argument that a return plane ticket does not demonstrate intent to leave but I fail to see how 6 months of work history and financial records will demonstrate an intent to depart that was not already evaluated. It just seems unnecessary and I have not found the site that says "carry all the same documents for the border entry point". Perhaps someone can guide me to that.

Comment: Was preparing an answer when I read Gayot was also preparing one so as usual we defer to him however although I have found no official reference demanding you carry the documents along,  what you are attempting to do is assert a right you do not have. Neither is it for you to make a definitive determination what should suffice or satisfy the immigration officer. You do not have a right to enter the UK. You do so at the pleasure of the UK.

Comment: @PaulofOsawatomie  no need for deference :)  Please add your answer and help the OP out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everyone entering the UK without 'Right of Abode' (or similar rights) is subject to an inspection by an Immigration Officer ([paragraph 2A of Schedule 2 to the Immigration Act 1971](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1971/77/schedule/2)), or in vernacular, a "landing interview".

An IO has broad powers handed down from Parliament that extend well beyond the immigration rules. They are empowered as agents for HMRC, the National Crime Agency, the Children's Act, the Human Rights Act, and other just about anything else that endangers or affects public welfare.

So they are entitled to conduct a landing interview and to ask anything they want and to see evidence for any statements that have transpired.  Moreover, they are empowered to detain people who have not produced sufficient evidence.

Having said that, let's turn to your question...

> It just seems unnecessary and I have not found the site that says
>   "carry all the same documents for the border entry point".

Here's a screen cap from the relevant site...[image]

You can reach this site by following the wizard at [Check if you need a UK visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y)

Note that this is not a rule. Instead it is *guidance* only. The massive bulk of arrivals do not carry evidence and never get challenged to produce it.  Notwithstanding this, it is an act of prudence and sagacity to prepare yourself to back up **ANYTHING** liable to arise in a landing interview. This includes financial evidence, hard evidence of onward travel, employment contracts, along with the more exotic evidence like children's birth certificates, marriage certificates, unusual luggage, notoriety, criminal history, and the like. They are entitled to ask for evidence if they want and it's all part of "what is". And they can detain you until you produce satisfactory evidence. Even Brits are subject to portions of the landing interview.

I always write to carry your evidence because it is "best practices" for a traveller (of any nationality).

Comment: Thanks - I acknowledge the referral to the requirement for same documents and accept that as written, so I will now comply as well. I just, in this world we live in, feel extremely uncomfortable travelling across the globe with print copies of pays slips and bank statements, proof of property ownerships, etc.

Comment: @Visaanxious oh! I forgot to add that part, or it was not asked. Either way you can open a new question about protecting personal data on those documents.

Comment: The "even brits" part was news to me, so I've [asked another question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/94873/what-can-a-british-national-be-asked-in-a-uk-landing-interview) to get more details

Comment: @Gagravarr read this one in the archives for a great example https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53975/children-with-a-different-surname-to-parent-uk-citizen-uk-passport-control